# Network WiFi extender creates another network that I cannot reach from home

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a second WiFi AP (TP-link) in my cellar. This AP is connected via Ethernet to the primary router and WiFi AP. The problem is that while on my home primary network I have my PC on:

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.241
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

In the cellar the secondary WiFi network is on 192.168.**1**.**255**.
This means that from my home I cannot reach services in the cellar WiFi network.

How can i solve it?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart  I do have the second router connected to one of the LAN port of first router. So it has 2 IPs. Its WiFi network is creating a new network/LAN. I am thinking to manually change its WiFi LAN address from 192.168.1.1 to something like 192.168.0.xxx

Comment: Yup, it's called bridging. I can write up an answer for you later if you would like.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart that would be great. I have looked in the manual of TP Link for the types of setup but it did not solve so far. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by setting up the router in AP mode and choosing an IP in the main network.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop. I totally forgot to come back and write an answer for you. Glad you got it figured out